# Run php from jquery click, return array from php file which calls another file

Tags: php, ajax, json, mysqli

yesterday i managed to get my data from a database outputting and storing to a java array. However that was on load, now that code wont work for on click. 
So I have read about ajax and have this function:

```
  var infArray = new Array();
  var country;
    $('#australia').click(function() {
        //console.log("you clicked"+txt);
        country = 'Australia';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/Maps.php',
            data: {country: country},
            success: function(data){
            alert("success"+data); // this will hold your $result value
            infArray = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log( 'Return:' + data );
            }           
        });
    });
```

By my understanding this opens the php file containing the function and allows you to use the variable "country" by using $_POST.

So my php file looks like this :

```
<?php
require '../classes/Mysql.php';

function get_Stockist(){ // if su = 0 then stockist if = 1 then member
    $mysql = new Mysql();
    $result = $mysql->getInfo($_POST['country']);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

so again in my eyes, $result is set to the result of the method :
in Mysql.php :

```
function getinfo($country){

    $rows = array();
    $query = "SELECT Name,add1 FROM stockistsWorld WHERE Country = '". mysql_escape_string($country) ."' LIMIT 5";
    //$query = "SELECT Name,add1 FROM stockistsUK LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
    /* numeric array */

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){

         $rows[] = $row;

        }
    return $rows;
}
```

However the result in my html is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call your function `get_Stockist()` in your PHP file that gets called by AJAX.
Add `get_Stockist()` to your PHP file to call your function.

And your other function is `getinfo`, without capital i.
So it would be `$mysql->getinfo($_POST['country']);` instead of `$mysql->getInfo($_POST['country']);`

Comment: I changed it to capital i, and just removed the method so now Maps.php looks like `<?php
require '../classes/Mysql.php';
require_once('../FirePHPCore/fb.php');
ob_start();
   fb('1', FirePHP::TRACE);
  $mysql = new Mysql();
    fb('2', FirePHP::TRACE);
  $result = $mysql->getInfo($_POST['country']);
    fb('3', FirePHP::TRACE);
  $res = 1;
    fb('4', FirePHP::TRACE);
  echo json_encode($result);
    fb('5', FirePHP::TRACE);
  ` ALSO INSTALLED FIREPHP SO GOOD!. I hope this is an  ok fix